# Proving that f'(x) is even if f(x) is odd and differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've seen some proofs but I don't really get it..I find it hard to understand..

I've done this so far:

\begin{eqnarray}  f'(x) &=& \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(x+h)}{h} \textit{ (since f(x) is odd } f(-x) = -f(x)) \\ &=& \lim_{h \to 0} 
\frac{-f(-x) + f(-x-h)}{h} \\ &=& \lim_{h -\to 0} \frac{f(-x-h) - f(-x)}{h}
\end{eqnarray}

But I don't know how to go from here and make it equal to $f'(-x)$.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is odd.  Write $g(x) = f(-x)$.  Now compute $g'$ with the chain rule and then by invoking the oddness of $f$.  Equate the results.  What happens?

Comment: Shouldn't I use the definition of a derivative for this though? I don't know how to use the chain rule on something like f(-x) which doesn't look like an ordinary function..

Comment: You can also do this.  Write out the limit using the fact that $f(-x) = -f(x)$.  This works too.

Comment: Here's how the chain rule is used in this case: $\dfrac{d}{dx}f(-x)$ $=f'(-x)\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}(-x)$ $= -f'(-x)$.  But it is also true that $\dfrac{d}{dx}f(-x)$ $=\dfrac{d}{dx}(-f(x))$ $=-\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x) = -f'(x)$.  Therefore $-f'(-x)=-f'(x)$, and therefore $f'(-x)=f'(x)$.  Consequently $f'$ is even.

Answer (score 5):

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{-f(-x)+f(-x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ Now set $-x=X,-x_0=X_0$ so $x\to x_0$ means $X\to X_0$ and: $$f'(x_0)=\lim_{X\to X_0}\frac{-f(X)+f(X_0)}{-X+X_0}=\lim_{X\to X_0}\frac{f(X)-f(X_0)}{X-X_0}=f'(X_0)=f'(-x_0),~~x,x_0\in D_f$$

Comment: Nice work, @Babak! +1